# add a span tag in an existing anchor tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add this tag `<span class="vantage-icon-arrow-up"></span>` inside the anchor without adding a callFunctions or eventFunctions

Current html is:

```
<a href="#" id="scroll-to-top" 
  class="scroll-to-top displayed showbutton" title="Back To Top"></a>`
```

Comment: what tag do you want to append?

Comment: Hello Ramon. Sorry I forgot to add the tag that I want to append. I have edited now my question about but this is the tag i want to append '<span class="vantage-icon-arrow-up"></span>'

Comment: is jquery good for an answer or javascript only?

Comment: I am not so sure to be honest. i believe i only need a simple javascript. some how the wordpress theme that my friend has a scroll to up button. the arrow doesnt show in the home page but so far in the inside pages is all fine. I only wish to add that "span" tag to fix the problem.

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem. Perhaps this is the issue: https://siteorigin.com/thread/icons-not-visible-in-new-vantage-install/

Comment: @rpalzona are you sure that the icon's are being loaded? as mplungjan suggested it might be the cause of this problem

Comment: @mplugjan - I am having the same problem with the siteorigin thread that you sent. thank you I am still looking and researching some answers...

Comment: @rpalzona could you provide us with a screenshot/ code of the html output on the website? if you use f12 to inspect the page and select that button

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to append it, this should suffice.

```
const target = document.getElementById('scroll-to-top');
target.innerHTML = '<span class="vantage-icon-arrow-up"></span>';
```

Comment: Hello mate @algef i tried the javascript and nothing happens. also my script before is document.getElementById("scroll-to-top").innerHTML += "<span class="vantage-icon-arrow-up"></span>"; did not work too... i really appreciate your response :)

Answer (score 0):

in jquery you can use the `.append()` function like this:

```js
$('#scroll-to-top').append('<span class="vantage-icon-arrow-up">i put this text here to show that it works</span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="scroll-to-top" class="scroll-to-top displayed showbutton" title="Back To Top"></a>
```

read more about it here: https://api.jquery.com/append/

in case of plain javascript it would be this:

```js
var anchor = document.getElementById('scroll-to-top');
anchor.innerHTML = '<span class="vantage-icon-arrow-up">i put this text here to show that it works</span>';
```

```html
<a href="#" id="scroll-to-top" class="scroll-to-top displayed showbutton" title="Back To Top"></a>
```

read more about innerHTML here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: Hello Ramon, thank youour  so much for your response. I did tried your suggestion but somehow it is still not working. I have solved the issue with css so far though not 100% happy with the result. i appreciate your response so much...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your friend is not loading his icons?

https://siteorigin.com/thread/search-and-scroll-to-top-icons-are-missing/
https://siteorigin.com/thread/icons-not-visible-in-new-vantage-install/

Anyway, here is a solution without script

```css
#scroll-to-top {
  text-decoration: none
}

#scroll-to-top::before {
  content: "▲";
  font-size: xx-large;
}

#scroll-to-top:hover {
  text-decoration: underline
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="scroll-to-top" class="scroll-to-top displayed showbutton" title="Back To Top"></a>
```

Comment: Hello @mplungjan thaornk you for your response it gave me an idea to customize instead the current css and not run any javascript as it is not working for some sor of reason. heres what i did so far

'
#scroll-to-top.displayed:before {
    content: "^";
}
#scroll-to-top.displayed{
    font-size: 28px;
    display: block;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
 font-family: auto;
    font-weight: bolder !important;
}'

Comment: You do not need .displayed on the CSS since #scroll-to-top is the same element

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your prompt and very helpful responses. I have solved the issue using css though I am not so 100% happy with the result. but the main goal now is to fix the issue. here is what I did so far getting idea from @mplungjan:

```
#scroll-to-top:before {
content: "^"; }

#scroll-to-top.displayed{
font-size: 28px;
display: block;
width: 28px;
height: 28px;
color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
font-family: auto;
font-weight: bolder !important;}
```

thank you everyone...